# How the Elasticsearch Suggester run when combining with query?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-suggester

I’m pretty new to Elasticsearch and planning to use the phrase suggester on my project. As mentioned in [the official document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html) the default suggest mode is “missing” means the suggestion would be generated if it cannot find the same phrase on the index. So I’m wondering if I add the suggester on the same request with the query does it mean the suggester would be executed after the query and only if it cannot find the phrase on index? Or the suggested would be executed separately by start from looking for the phase on the index?

My concern is I don’t want the suggester to run if it found the phrase in the index while the query is execute

Comment: The suggestion is executed separately. The suggestion will be executed even though query not find documents.

Comment: @rabbitbr Thanks for the comment, but my concern is, when the query is found on the documents would the suggestion also run?